# C# Excel worksheet_change not ALWAYS firing

Tags: c#, excel, worksheet-function

I've been working on an excel add-in.

This is the constructor for the addin:

```
        public AddinModule()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            InitializeComponent();
            AddinFinalize += new ADXEvents_EventHandler(FinalizeAddIn);
            AddinInitialize += new ADXEvents_EventHandler(InitializeAddIn);
            OnError += new ADXError_EventHandler(OnErrorAddIn);
            EventDel_CellsChange += new Excel.DocEvents_ChangeEventHandler(CellsChange);
        }
```

There is a button that, among other things, creates a new worksheet, and after it has been created, the CellsChange method is added to the worksheet.Change event, as follows:

```
//some code
                CreateWorkSheet();
                sheet = ExcelApp.ActiveSheet as Excel.Worksheet;
                sheet.Change += EventDel_CellsChange;
//some code
```

Column A values are loaded when the worksheet is created. This works as expected. Columns B to E values depend on the one selected in the previous column. The problem that I'm having is that a change in any of these columns **not always** trigger the event. I have obviously debugged the addin, adding breakpoints to the cellschange method, but the result is the same: sometimes it breaks in the breakpoint, and sometimes it doesn't. When it **does** stop, everything works just fine. Once the event is not triggered, it won't work again, unless the worksheet is deleted, and added by pressing the previously mentioned button. Am I missing something?

Finally, the cellsChange method:

```
private void CellsChange(Excel.Range Target)
        {

            Excel.Worksheet sheet = null;
            Excel.Range rng = null;

            Excel.Range columns = null;

            Excel.Range column = null;
            try
            {
                foreach (Excel.Range c in Target.Cells)
                {
                    if (c.Row != 1 && c.Column < (int)Columnas.Column6 && c.Value2 != null)
                    {

                        sheet = CurrentInstance.ExcelApp.ActiveSheet as Excel.Worksheet;
                        string[] values = null;
                        string AValue;
                        string BValue;
                        switch (c.Column)
                        {
                            case (int)Columnas.A:
                                values = GetBValues(c.Value2.ToString());
                                rng = sheet.Cells[c.Row, (int)Columnas.B] as Excel.Range;
                                break;
                            case (int)Columnas.B:
                                AValue = (string)(sheet.Cells[c.Row, (int)Columnas.A] as Excel.Range).Value;
                                values = GetCValues(AValue, c.Value2.ToString());
                                rng = sheet.Cells[c.Row, (int)Columnas.C] as Excel.Range;
                                break;
                            case (int)Columnas.C:
                                AValue = (string)(sheet.Cells[c.Row, (int)Columnas.A] as Excel.Range).Value;
                                BValue = (string)(sheet.Cells[c.Row, (int)Columnas.B] as Excel.Range).Value;
                                values = GetDValues(AValue, BValue, c.Value2.ToString());
                                rng = sheet.Cells[c.Row, (int)Columnas.D] as Excel.Range;
                                break;
                            case (int)Columnas.D:
                                if (c.Value2.ToString() == FUTURE)
                                {
                                    AValue = (string)(sheet.Cells[c.Row, (int)Columnas.A] as Excel.Range).Value;
                                    BValue = (string)(sheet.Cells[c.Row, (int)Columnas.B] as Excel.Range).Value;
                                    string moneda = (string)(sheet.Cells[c.Row, (int)Columnas.C] as Excel.Range).Value;
                                    values = GetEValues(AValue, BValue, moneda, c.Value2.ToString());
                                    rng = sheet.Cells[c.Row, (int)Columnas.E] as Excel.Range;
                                }
                                break;
                            default:
                                break;
                        }


                        if (values != null)
                        {

                            sheet.Unprotect(Type.Missing);
                            columns = rng.Columns;
                            column = columns[1] as Excel.Range;
                            column.Validation.Delete();
                            SetRangeFormat(column, FormatType.Text);
                            column.Validation.Add(Excel.XlDVType.xlValidateList, Excel.XlDVAlertStyle.xlValidAlertInformation,
                                    Type.Missing, string.Join(Separator, values), Type.Missing);

                            column.Validation.InCellDropdown = true;
                            column.Locked = false;

                            sheet.Protect(Type.Missing, false, true, false, false, true, true, true, false, false, true, false, false, true, true, true);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (sheet != null)
                {
                    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(sheet);
                }

                if (columns != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(columns);
                if (rng != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(rng);
                if (column != null)
                {

                    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(column);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I'm wondering if there is any `Application.EnableEvents = False` in the rest of your code

Comment: Do you have access for example in the "OnErrorAddIn" code?

Comment: @anefeletos, no, there isn't any `Application.EnableEvents = false`.